# The Items page in a Document List is no longer rendered

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I'm trying to understand a strange behavior in a Document List but I'm running out of ideas.

The SharePoint site has been created with the new modern team site template (STS#3)
I have a Document List with a custom content type attached to it. Nothing special about the content type (columns of type DateTime, Text, Lookup ...).

On some documents (I didn't find out common links to these documents), when the mouse rolls over the name of the document, a popup card opens (as it should be) but the total number of view is missing and the UI is still loading (after a huge amount of time)...

[image]

However, the Rest Api call has successfully returned :

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://cloudosb.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/$metadata#oneDrive.itemActivityStat",
  "@oneDrive.displayNamesOfFileViewers": true,
  "startDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "endDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "isTrending": true,
  "access": { "actionCount": 19, "actorCount": 8 },
  "incompleteData": {
  "wasThrottled": false,
  "resultsPending": false,
  "notSupported": false
  },
  "activities": []
}
```

There is a javascript error in the console :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
  at e._getCardHeight (splistdeferred-mini-e67e6dc1.js:1)
  at e._setHightAndAnalyticsResult (splistdeferred-mini-e67e6dc1.js:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (splistdeferred-mini-e67e6dc1.js:1)
  at e._emitChange (splistdeferred-mini-e67e6dc1.js:1)
  at splistdeferred-mini-e67e6dc1.js:1
  at Object.k [as _notify] (spofiles-mini-35f6fd2e.js:1)
  at Object.enter (spofiles-mini-35f6fd2e.js:1)
  at d._run (spofiles-mini-35f6fd2e.js:1)
  at d._completed (spofiles-mini-35f6fd2e.js:1)
```

The second time the mouse rolls over the name of the document, there is the same javascript error, but the entire list is no longer rendered (the error is thrown on the componentDidUpdate react event, so I assume that all sub components can't be rendered)

This behavior has only be detected on the Modern Site Experience, If I come back to the Classic Experience, this problem doesn't appear.

Thanks for your help.

Romain